# How to terminate a program in linux command line (ctrl+c and ctrl+z are not working)?

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-terminal

I ran following command on linux terminal `hdparm -T -t /dev/sda`. It is not giving any output and i am unable to stop this by `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+z`. How to terminate this program with out restarting system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ctrl+c` (SIGINT) and `ctrl+z` (SIGTSTP) can be handled (or ignored) by processes. If you are sure that you want to kill the process then you need to use SIGTERM (can be handled by processes) first and SIGKILL, if that doesn't work.

Open another terminal and do a ps aux|grep hdparm to get the process id and then pass that process id to kill command. If you are sure that there is only one hdparm process that is running then you can do the following as well:

```
# this will pass SIGTERM
ps aux | grep hdparm | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill 

# this will pass SIGKILL
ps aux | grep hdparm | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

Comment: isn't it `print $1`?

Comment: I can't open another terminal, It's a single terminal system(Embedded system)

Comment: @eazar001 $1 is username

Comment: @Chinna Usually for Linux you can do ALT+CTRL+F6 to open alternate terminal. Replace F6 with anything between F2 to F7.

Comment: @Chinna, oh right, sorry I was thinking about `ps ax`